# Bibliotecas para comunicação entre Arduino e Android

Tags: java, android, arduino

Eu sou um iniciante Arduino programador tentando fazer uma conexão com o meu celular (Android) e / ou o meu laptop usando Java.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e até agora eu encontrei três exemplos de como isso pode funcionar:

1. Usando bibliotecas rxtx (GNU IO)
2. Usando Java IO (Sockets).
3. Usando cliente HTTP.

Eu estou feliz que eu estou cada vez mais perto de compreender como a informação vai de Java ao Arduino e do Arduino para Java, mas e sobre estas três formas há para implementá-lo? Qual é a principal diferença?

Em algumas semanas (após algum estudo) estou ansioso para comunicar meu celular Android com Arduino com Bluetooth (estou usando rede loca com cabo até o momento), qual a melhor biblioteca a seguir?

Comment: @DBX8, recomenda-se esperar os 5 minutos nos quais o usuário tem direito a modificar o post sem que isso fique no histórico (grace period, em inglês)

Answer (score 8):

Há dois lados para se analisar nessa situação: o lado do Arduino e o lado do Android.

## Arduino

Do lado do Arduino, você tem diversas opções, mas as mais comuns são:

- Utilizar a classe `Serial`, para enviar e receber dados via os terminais `RX` e `TX` da placa. Em seguida, você acopla um adaptador *Bluetooth* a esses terminais, e ele se encarregará de fazer a transmissão/recepção (existem diversos modelos, marcas e tamanhos de adaptadores Bluetooth para Arduino, resta escolher um deles).
- Se você possuir um *WiFi Shield*, então você pode conectar o *shield*  ao Arduino, e utilizar a classe `WiFi` para se comunicar via HTTP, ou TCP ou UDP (depende da sua necessidade). Essa solução costuma ser um pouco mais cara que a do *Bluetooth*, em termos de custo $. Contudo, já existem diversos exemplos que acompanham a IDE do Arduino para auxiliar nos primeiros passos (menu `File > Examples > WiFi`).

## Android

Do lado do Android, depende de qual das duas soluções você escolheu do lado do Arduino.

### Bluetooth

Caso tenha optado pelo *Bluetooth*, sua solução será parear o Arduino em seu dispositivo Android, e utilizar os serviços das classes [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) e [BluetoothSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) para iniciar uma comunicação utilizando SPP (*Serial Port Profile*).

Existe um exemplo bem completo de como fazer isso [nesse site](http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php).

### WiFi - Socket

Caso tenha optado por utilizar o *WiFi Shield* do lado do Arduino, então resta a você decidir qual o modo de comunicação que você utilizará.

Você pode optar por simplesmente enviar e receber dados crus através de um [soquete](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soquete_de_rede) TCP, utilizando a classe [Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) do Android. Existem diversos tutoriais ensinando a utilizar soquetes, [eis um interessante](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).

### WiFi - HTTP

Ainda, você pode optar por enviar os dados através do protocolo HTTP.

Com esse tipo de solução você nem precisa efetivamente criar uma aplicação Android, pois a comunicação pode ser feita através de um browser comum, de qualquer sistema operacional. Existe um ótimo exemplo, bem simples, para isso junto com a IDE do Arduino: `File > Examples > WiFi > SimpleWebServerWiFi`.

Agora, se você realmente quiser criar uma aplicação Android e se comunicar via HTTP, você pode utilizar diversas classes, dentre elas [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)

Existe um pequeno exemplo de como fazer isso nessa outra pergunta do SO: [How do I use the Simple HTTP client in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android)

---

Quanto as minhas experiências pessoais, costumo fazer a comunicação nessa ordem (ordem de preferência no meu dia-a-dia):

1. *Bluetooth*: O adaptador *Bluetooth* é mais barato, e você não precisa de um monitor, ou um display, para descobrir qual foi o IP obtido pelo *WiFi Shield* do Arduino, toda vez que ele se conectar ao WiFi
2. *WiFi Shield* via soquete: Enviar e receber dados crus, através de uma conexão TCP entre os dois, costuma acelerar a resposta do Arduino, pois ele não tem que se preocupar com o protocolo HTTP, e todos os dados extras que são enviados por causa do protocolo
3. *WiFi Shield* via HTTP: Apesar de fazer com que mais dados trafeguem pelos dois lados, e de a resposta nem sempre ser tão rápida do lado do Arduino, ao utilizar essa solução você pode conectar o Arduino não só a um dispositivo, mas a vários dispositivos, inclusive **sem** precisar criar uma aplicação Android, pois essa comunicação pode ser feita através de um browser convencional de qualquer sistema operacional

Comment: muito obrigado, foi de grande ajuda sua resposta. Sei que parece pouco profissional, mas poderia ver se consegue me ajudar no post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16234/conexao-com-socket-android    ?? Estou tentando acender o LED13 já faz bastante tempo, e com Jbutton deu certo. Copiei exatamente o mesmo código para o android e não dá certo.

Comment: Oi @user8649! Sem problemas! Acabei de fazer um comentário a sua outra pergunta. Aqui no StackOverflow, você deve indicar se a resposta era ou não a que você queria, através daquele ícone √ que fica logo abaixo da pontuação da resposta ;)