# Conexão com Socket provoca uma exceção no Android

Tags: java, android, arduino

O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente quando apenas utilizado com um JButton, mas ao passar para o Android acontece a exceção (Exception).

Localizei que o erro está em

```
clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
```

mas não consigo entender o porquê do erro.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

private static final String serverIP="192.168.1.177";
private static final int serverPort=80;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

    button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());    

}

public class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        // Message that will be sent to Arduino
        String msgToServer;

        // Received message will be stored here
        String msgFromServer;

        try{

            // Making the socket connection
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);

            // Debug
            System.out.println("Connected to:"+serverIP+" on port:"+serverPort);


            // OutputStream to Arduino-Server
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            //BufferedReader from Arduino-Server
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            // Message tha will be sent
            msgToServer = "Turn ON LED 13";

            // Sending the message
            outToServer.writeBytes(msgToServer + '\n');

            // Debug
            System.out.println("sending to Arduino-Server: "+msgToServer);

            // Recieving the answer
            msgFromServer = inFromServer.readLine();

            // Print the answer
            System.out.println("recieved from Arduino-Server: " + msgFromServer);

            // Close the socket. Don't do this if you want to keep the connection
            clientSocket.close();

        }

        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

}   

}
```

Comment: O código parece correto. Seria interessante ter mais informações sobre qual `Exception` está acontecendo. Mas, à primeira vista, não encontrei onde você define `serverIP` e `serverPort`. Será que ambos possuem valores antes da chamada `Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);`? Além disso, o correto seria criar uma `Thread` ou uma `Task` para fazer essa comunicação, e não fazer de dentro do clique do botão, pois pode travar o programa e o Android poderá indicar um ANR...

Comment: Segundo a documentação da classe Socket, "public Socket(String dstName, int dstPort) throws UnknownHostException, IOException" deveria ser a UnknownHostException ou a IOException, mas quando tento comparar (boolean exception = e.equals(UnknownHostException.class) ou boolean exception = e.equals(IOException.class);) sempre retornar false. O serverIP e o serverPort estão definidos logo abaixo da linha

Comment: Então, para saber se um objeto é de uma classe específica você deve utilizar `intanceof`, por exemplo: `if (e instanceof UnknownHostException)`. Contudo, a forma correta para tratar exceções é utilizar a estrutura `try-catch`, criando um `catch` para cada classe de exceção desejada. Agora, sobre esse erro, eu recomendo trocar a linha do construtor para `Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), serverPort)`, mas, você está mesmo inicializando as variáveis `serverIP` e `serverPort`?

Comment: Este código está rodando em um device real ou no emulador? Digo isso porque o emulador está numa rede isolada da rede local, tem apenas comunicação com a máquina host. E o endereço para acessar a máquina host é 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Adicionou permissão de internet ao manifesto?

Answer (score 1):

Como disse o Lucas,
Verifique se no seu AndroidManifest.xml tem a seguintes permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Abraços